# How to wait till completing first operation before starting second in DbContext EF multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework-core

My project is in multithreading. I am using EF Core. Sometimes I am getting error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext

I research this problem and found couple notes about it:

- EF Core is not safe threading
- The best solution is creating new context in each threads

But sometimes I need to use the same context in multiple threads. I reproduced the issue.
My model:

```
public class School
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public Guid SchoolGuid { get; set; }
    public virtual School School { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Backpack> Backpacks { get; set; }
}    
public class Backpack
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public Guid StudentGuid { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Reproduce steps:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainContext mainContext = new MainContext();
    CreateData(mainContext);
    var task1 = Task.Run(new Action(() => GetStudents(mainContext)));
    var task2 = Task.Run(new Action(() => GetBackpacks(mainContext)));
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
}

static void GetStudents(MainContext mainContext)
{
    var students = mainContext.Set<Student>().ToList();
}

static void GetBackpacks(MainContext mainContext)
{
    var backpacks = mainContext.Set<Backpack>().ToList();
}

static void CreateData(MainContext mainContext)
{
    if (!mainContext.Set<School>().Any())
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
          var school = new School() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), Address = $"Scho olAddress{i}", Name = $"SchoolName{i}" };
          mainContext.Add(school);
          for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
          {
             var student = new Student() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), LastName = $"LastName{j}", FirstName = $"FirstName{j}", DOB = DateTime.Today, School = school };
             mainContext.Add(student);
             for (int l = 0; l < 100; l++)
             {
                var backpack = new Backpack() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = $"Name{i}", Student = student, Cost = l };
                mainContext.Add(backpack);
             }
          }
       }
       mainContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I want second operating wait until completing first operation. How can I configure this? I may have a lots of thread which can use same context. How can build queue of using context automatically?

Using lock helps for some use cases but not for all:

```
static void GetStudents(MainContext mainContext)
        {
            lock (mainContext)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Loading Students are started");
                var students = mainContext.GetEntities<Student>().ToList();
                Console.WriteLine("Students are loaded");
            }
        }

        static void GetBackpacks(MainContext mainContext)
        {
            lock (mainContext)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Loading Backpakcs are started");
                var backpacks = mainContext.GetEntities<Backpack>().ToList();
                Console.WriteLine("Backpakcs are loaded");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make it async and await the result. Check if it was a succes. If yes continue to next

Comment: A DbContext is a unit of work, not a database connection. It's not meant to be long-lived or reused.  It can't be used from multiple threads nor does it make sense to do so. The bug is in your `Main` method. The methods `GetStudents` and `GetBackpacks` make little sense too - to get any benefit from asynchronous execution you need to use `ToListAsync`, not start another thread and block it with `ToList()`

Comment: Finally, the code is creating new DbSets left and right. There's a reason no tutorial does this. A DbContext isn't a connection, it's a Unit of Work, for specific entities, exposed through the DbSet repository properties. At best, this is making the code harder to read. Since each `Backpack` has a `Student` though, you could load all related objects at once with `myContext.Backpacks.Include(x=>x.Student)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos These methods just for reproducing my problem. The main problem is there can be two threads requesting one context. I cannot follow up all threads. I want to fix it globaly somthing like: GetEntities() {  if(context.IsUsing) wait().ContinueWith()....;  }

Comment: "sometimes I need to use the same context in multiple threads" no you really don't.  Your database can handle multiple concurrent requests, but they just need to come from different DbContext instances.

Comment: If you really can't ensure only one thread calls your DAL object, consider creating new `DbContext` in each DAL method (instead of injecting it in c'tor). It's against best practices and has performance penalty but if you have no choice it can solve your issue.

Comment: `there can be two threads requesting one context` so don't do that. That's not how DbContext is used. Again and again, a DbContext isn't a connection, it represents a *single unit of work* - the objects and changes to the objects made in a single business transaction. While async operations make sense, multi-threading *doesn't*. All objects in a query can and *will* be loaded in a single SQL query if possible. All changes *will* be persisted in a single transaction.

Comment: @DilshodK perhaps the real question should be *why are you trying to use multiple threads*? Why are you trying to load all objects into memory? That's the problem you need to solve, and multiple concurrent loads operations *isn't* the answer

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to fix CreateData. Remove  mainContext.Add(scholl) and  mainContext.Add(student). Use only mainContext.Set Backpack ().Add(backpack);

```
static void CreateData(MainContext mainContext)
{
    if (!mainContext.Set<School>().Any())
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
          var school = new School() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), Address = $"Scho olAddress{i}", Name = $"SchoolName{i}" };
         
          for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
          {
             var student = new Student() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), LastName = $"LastName{j}", FirstName = $"FirstName{j}", DOB = DateTime.Today, School = school };
           
             for (int l = 0; l < 100; l++)
             {
                var backpack = new Backpack() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = $"Name{i}", Student = student, Cost = l };
                mainContext.Set<Backpack>().Add(backpack);
             }
          }
       }
       mainContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You have to create  a new context object for each task.

```
MainContext mainContext1 = new MainContext();
CreateData(mainContext1);
MainContext mainContext2 = new MainContext();
CreateData(mainContext2);

    var task1 = Task.Run(new Action(() => GetStudents(mainContext1)));
    var task2 = Task.Run(new Action(() => GetBackpacks(mainContext2)));
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

But if you can't do this then this is maximum you can get from EF.

```
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
    MainContext mainContext = new MainContext();
    CreateData(mainContext);
     await GetStudents(mainContext);
     await GetBackpacks(mainContext);
        
        
    }
   static async Task GetStudents(MainContext mainContext)
{
  await mainContext.Set<Student>().ToListAsync();
}

static async Task GetBackpacks(MainContext mainContext)
{
   await mainContext.Set<Backpack>().ToListAsync();
}
}
```

but I don't see any practical use in the code above so probably you need this

```
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
    MainContext mainContext = new MainContext();
    CreateData(mainContext);
    var students=  await GetStudents(mainContext);
     var backPacks= await GetBackpacks(mainContext);
        
        
    }
   static async Task<List<Student>> GetStudents(MainContext mainContext)
{
    return await mainContext.Set<Student>().ToListAsync();
}

static async TaskList<Backpack>> GetBackpacks(MainContext mainContext)
{
   return await mainContext.Set<Backpack>().ToListAsync();
}
}
```

Comment: I want to run GetStudents and GetBackpacks in the same time. I just make a simple project to reproduce  my problem. You awaiting GetStudents and then run GetBackpacks. At my project I have a lots of running threads that I cannot to follow up each of them. Thats why I need fix this problem automatialy not by configuring each thread

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but I need EF

Comment: I showed you the maximum that you can get from EF. Or you have to create new dbcontext for each task.

Comment: For some use cases I cannot use new context and I need to get this work somehow without creating new context and running all action in single thread

Comment: EF takes care about running async task in a single thread. You sholdn't worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use DbContext for concurrent queries. DbContext is not thread safe.
Correct way to use DbContext with async is:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    MainContext mainContext = new MainContext();
    CreateData(mainContext);
    await GetStudents(mainContext);
    await GetBackpacks(mainContext);
}
```

Otherwise you have to create new DbContext for each task.